# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow c#

Tags: c#, winapi, win32-process

I am getting the following error when unlocking a file

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
>
> System.IntPtr.ToInt32

I suspect it is the following line to `pBuffer.ToInt32()` :

```
IntPtr iPtr = new IntPtr(pBuffer.ToInt32() + (i * Marshal.SizeOf(fi3)));
```

I am unable to reproduce the error myself and the error is not displaying the correct line number. I am looking for a way to reproduce this or any feedback on the possible cause.  Thanks

```
public void Close()
{
        const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;
        int readEntries;
        int totalEntries;
        IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        FILE_INFO_3 fi3 = new FILE_INFO_3();
        int iStatus = NetFileEnum(this.HostName, this.HostPathToShare + this.FileNameFromShare, null, 3, ref pBuffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out readEntries, out totalEntries, pBuffer);
        if (iStatus == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < readEntries; i++)
            {
                IntPtr iPtr = new IntPtr(pBuffer.ToInt32() + (i * Marshal.SizeOf(fi3)));
                fi3 = (FILE_INFO_3)Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr, typeof(FILE_INFO_3));
                NetFileClose(this.HostName, fi3.fi3_id);
            }
        }
        NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);
}

[DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int NetFileClose(
    string servername,
    int id);

[DllImport("Netapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);

[DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int NetFileEnum(
     string servername,
     string basepath,
     string username,
     int level,
     ref IntPtr bufptr,
     int prefmaxlen,
     out int entriesread,
     out int totalentries,
     IntPtr resume_handle
);
```

**Update**

I added the win32 apis code.

The below answers look correct and the machine is 64 bit.  But I am unable to reproduce it on the dev server despite the dev environment being 64 bit.  Any ideas to reproduce the error?

Comment: Your example code doesnt not mention a ToInt64 I think as a result it could be very hard for any of us to reproduce it if you cant either and you have all your code.

Comment: @BugFinder   I updated the code to include win32 code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is caused by your code running in a 64 bit context and returning a pointer address that lies outside the range addressable with 32 bits, so `.ToInt32()` throws.

Call [Environment.Is64BitProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect whether your process is running in 32 or 64 bit, and convert the address accordingly:

```
long pointerAddress;

if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    pointerAddress = pBuffer.ToInt64(); 
}
else
{
    pointerAddress = pBuffer.ToInt32(); 
}

var fileInfoPointer = new IntPtr(pointerAddress + (i * Marshal.SizeOf(fi3)));
```

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster.  I am going to update the project.   I am having trouble replicating the error.  I tried changing the target platform to x64 with no luck of producing the error. But I am using iis express

Comment: Thanks.  I was put in production for a month with no issues.  It took a while to validate since I couldn't replilicate

Comment: Targeting x86 resolve the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors in the code right off:

1. You set your `pBuffer` to 0, and never actually allocate it.  It *should* error when you pass it to `NetFileEnum`, although that is a Win32 API function, so it may not notice.
2. You convert pBuffer `.ToInt32()`, which *should* work when compiled for x86 specifically, but if you have Any CPU or x64 as your target platform, this is going to be a problem also.

Comment: From [NetFileEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525378.aspx): *"bufptr [out]: [...] This buffer is allocated by the system [...]"*

Comment: Matt - This is a asp.net application.  What do you suggest to do to resolve it.