# How to remove a file lock

Tags: c#, .net

I have an service to move files from a working folder to backup folder.  The folders are on a network share, so at times we will open a file, using something like notepad, to look at it.  People are not (well, shouldn't) be editing, just looking.

When we try to move the file, I get permission denied.  I'm looking for a way in C# to force remove a file lock, so the service can move the file to the backup folder.

Comment: is this on windows? if you have critical files, then make them read-only for other users, otherwise any process can lock it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to **copy** them instead of move? move will delete the files from the source folder after copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use P/Invoke. These are the functions you care about:

```
[DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int NetFileEnum(string servername, string basepath, string username, int level, ref IntPtr bufptr, int prefmaxlen, out int entriesread, out int totalentries, IntPtr resume_handle);

[DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int NetFileClose(string servername, int id);

[DllImport("Netapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr buffer);
```

Here's some code similar to what I've used with success:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct FILE_INFO_3
{
    public int fi3_id;
    public int fi3_permission;
    public int fi3_num_locks;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string fi3_pathname;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string fi3_username;
}

private static FILE_INFO_3[] GetLockedFiles(string server, string path)
{
    const int MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = -1;

    int dwReadEntries;
    int dwTotalEntries;
    IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
    FILE_INFO_3 pCurrent = new FILE_INFO_3();
    List<FILE_INFO_3> files = new List<FILE_INFO_3>();

    int dwStatus = NetFileEnum(server, path, null, 3, ref pBuffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out dwReadEntries, out dwTotalEntries, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (dwStatus == 0)
    {
        for (int dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < dwReadEntries; dwIndex++)
        {
            IntPtr iPtr = new IntPtr(pBuffer.ToInt32() + (dwIndex * Marshal.SizeOf(pCurrent)));
            pCurrent = (FILE_INFO_3)Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr, typeof(FILE_INFO_3));
            files.Add(pCurrent);
        }
    }

    NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer);

    return files.ToArray();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FILE_INFO_3[] lockedFiles = GetLockedFiles("someservername", @"C:\somepath");

    foreach (FILE_INFO_3 lockedFile in lockedFiles)
    {
        int dwStatus = NetFileClose(_serverName, lockedFile.fi3_id);
        // Check dwStatus for success here
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** As noted by the OP in the comments below, when compiling as 64-bit, you need to use ToInt64 instead of ToInt32. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478303/arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-c-sharp).

Comment: Cool, I've give them a shot.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I guess this can leave some files corrupt or incomplete? Probably safer to just copy the file without closing it.

Comment: So, maybe a safer approach to this would be for locked files, copy file to new location, then kill the lock.  Also, I'm getting ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (NetFileEnum returning 5).  I found similar code to what you posted and get the 5.  I just tried yours and I get the same 5.  Thanks for the code, btw.  Investigating.

Comment: @BCarlson Are you an admin on the server where the network share is? You'll need to be.

Comment: @BCarlson Also, the corrupt/incomplete file problem is easily resolved by altering user permissions on the folder. If they shouldn't be editing the files, just remove their modify permissions.

Comment: Ok I have it returning successfully, now just need to create a locked file condition.  I expected that using notepad to open a text file would do it.

Comment: @BCarlson Please accept this answer so others can benefit from it. Thanks.

Comment: @BCarlson Notepad releases the lock on the file after it has finished opening the file.

Comment: Ok, so I'm able to get a listing, but getting a very large value for pBuffer.ToInt32() so when I add the dwindex and pcurrent size, I'm getting overflow exception.  For example pBuffer.ToInt32() returns 104,163,486,504 one result.

Comment: @itsme86 Any idea why I could be getting the buffer overflow?  I haven't see any typos/missing code.

Comment: I found that on 64bit, the code is just slightly different. pBuffer.ToInt32 becomes pBuffer.ToInt64.  This is where I found the answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478303/arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-c-sharp

Comment: @BCarlson Thanks, I've updated the answer in case others encounter this.